# When i tried to get data from url using nodejs it works properly on windows but when i tried same from ubuntu server its does not work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, web, screen-scraping

I am using node-fetch library in nodejs for this purpose.
There is no change in script which i use in windows and ubuntu

The server is provided by Hetzner

Need to know the reason and solution

Comment: What do you mean by `get data from url`? Please provide some code snippets.

Comment: const fetch = require("node-fetch");
response = await fetch(url,{method:"GET",headers:headers});const json = await response.json();
console.log(json)

Comment: or simply asked i am getting error in this command on Ubuntu server 
curl https://poocoin.app/.....
Need specific command which will help